# How to see what are the analysed tokens being indexed in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Given a source value "New-Value", say I have a `keyword` field, I know it is indexed as "New-Value" untouched, and then a `text` field, I know it is indexed as "new", "value" two lowercase tokens. Now for some custom fields with some custom analyser, instead of carefully tracing the index definition myself, is there an easy way to query what is being indexed from an existing index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the [fielddata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html) in order to achieve it, its not enabled on `text` fields, after that you can get the tokens created for a field in ES inverted index:

**Complete example**

**Index mapping**

```
{
    "mappings" :{
        "properties" :{
            "foo" :{
                "type" : "text",
                "fielddata": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index sample docs**

```
{
    "foo" : "Bar"
}

{
    "foo" : "Bar and Baz"
}
```

**And search query to fetch the tokens in inverted index for both sample docs**

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "docvalue_fields": [
        {
            "field": "foo"
        }
    ]
}
```

And result

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "myindex",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "foo": "Bar"
                },
                "fields": {
                    "foo": [
                        "bar"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "myindex",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "foo": "Bar and Baz"
                },
                "fields": {
                    "foo": [
                        "and",
                        "bar",
                        "baz"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! And for my order version, I actually need `"docvalue_fields": ["foo"]`

Comment: @user1589188 glad I was helpful :)